# why call.call invokes function

Tags: javascript, call

Here if I have a function which logs "called my function"

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('called my function')
}

Function.prototype.call.call(myFunction) // => "called my function"
```

while during a single `call` like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('called my function')
}
Function.prototype.call(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `someFunction.call(foo)`, it means to call `someFunction` while passing `foo` as the `this` parameter. Normally you have `someObject.someFunction()`, which passes `someObject` as `this` implicitly, but with `.call` you can set `this` to anything you want. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call.

So what does `Function.prototype.call(myFunction)` do? Well, it calls `Function.prototype`, passing `myFunction` as `this`. What does calling `Function.prototype` do? According to the ECMA specification:

> The Function prototype object is itself  a  Function  object (its [[Class]]  is `"Function"`) that, when invoked, accepts any arguments and returns `undefined`.

That's why `Function.prototype.call(myFunction)` has no visible effect.

On the other hand, `Function.prototype.call.call(myFunction)` calls `Function.prototype.call` (which is itself a function!), passing `myFunction` as `this`. What does this do? Exactly the same as `myFunction.call()`: When you look up the `call` property of a function object, you get it from `Function.prototype` anyway (through object inheritance). So what does this do? It calls `myFunction` with no (normal) arguments, but the value of `this` it sees is a bit tricky: If the function is in strict mode, `this` will be `undefined`; if it is non-strict, `this` will be the global object (a.k.a. `window` in browsers).

This is also the same behavior you get from `myFunction()` (i.e. not calling it on an object). In other words, `Function.prototype.call.call(foo)` is just a (very) roundabout way of writing `foo()`.

Comment: Function.prototype.call(myFunction) does nothing because the context of the function call is still the prototype.It's actually doing something.

Comment: @rupps What do you mean by "context"?

Comment: @rupps It's doing nothing because `Function.prototype` is a function with an empty body.

Comment: @melpomene then why Function.prototype.call(myFunction()) logs the result

Comment: the "this".... when you access directly a prototype function (as you know!), the "this" you provide is the object where the prototype functions will be executed. this case is tricky, because the function "call" relies on its parent "this", so when you call Function.prototype.call(myFunction) you are calling the function "prototype" !! (believe it or not protoype is itself a function) ... It's not "mozilla does nothing", but just calls the function prototype

Comment: @Hemant Because `myFunction()` calls `myFunction` first (which does the logging), then passes its return value (`undefined`) to `Function.prototype.call`, which in turn calls `Function.prototype` with `this` set to `undefined` (which, in non-strict functions, turns into the global object). `Function.prototype` then ignores `this` and immediately returns.

Comment: on the other hand Function.prototype.call.call IS calling myFunction, that's what I tried to explain in my answer even though the whole issue is pretty funny

Comment: @rupps Yes, that's what I've been saying? "*So what does `Function.prototype.call(myFunction)` do? Well, it calls `Function.prototype`*". I know it's a function. The call does nothing because it's an empty function. I don't know if the specification requires it to be empty.

Comment: @melpomene yeah, that's what I was saying also, I guess we both agree, just wanted to point out about your answer that it's not it's not doing "anything", but  just calling the esoteric function `prototype()`

Comment: @rupps Updated my answer. I actually looked it up in ECMA-262 (1997) and the 5.1 edition, and it is standard.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `call` itself does not expect a function as an argument and will not invoke it's argument as a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Rather, `call` is member function of all `Function` objects defined in their `prototype` which enables you to invoke a specific implementation of a member function while passing the argument to be used as `this` in the function invocation. Since `call` itself is a `Function`, it too has a `call` `member` function.

One use case of this is emulation of the `super` concept in e.g. Java. Consider another example with a function other than `call`:

```js
function Foo() {
  console.log('Foo');
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log('Foo bar');
};

function Baz() {
    console.log('Baz');
}

Baz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

Baz.prototype.bar = function () {
    Foo.prototype.bar.call(this);
        // Call the super class implementation of `bar`
    console.log('Baz bar');
};

var baz = new Baz();
baz.bar();
```

Answer (score -1):

### A little context:

`call` is a function that belongs to the `Function` object, as you probably know.

So if we have this function: (note the **this**)

```
function invite(where) {
   alert ("hi "+this.name+" do you want come to "+where);
}
```

and this object:

```
var obj = { name:"PETER" }
```

we could do

```
invite.call(obj, "the cinema")
```

- The first parameter to call is the CONTEXT. The function will be executed within the context of that object, that's why the alert will display "PETER" for this.name
- The second parameters and so on are the parameters, that's why the alert will display "the cinema".

### The second case: Function.prototype.call.call

`Function.prototype.call` is the raw "call" function of the function object. So you are accessing this function directly, and want to call it for your object ("call the function call"):

```
 Function.prototype.call.call
```

You want the function "call" to be called within the context of your function myFunction (first call paramerer):

```
 Function.prototype.call.call(myFunction, ...);
```

That is, in fact, equivalent to

```
 nyFunction.call(...);
```

### The first case

The first case does nothing because prototype is itself a function (that you can ".call" :) , so

```
Function.prototype.call(whatever)
```

would just be equivalent to

```
Function.prototype();
```

executed in the context of your function